# Spring Framework (V2.5) - Using actionpath in ref attribute in a bean definition

Tags: spring

I am a pretty newcomer for Spring Framework.
This is regarding referencing another bean using ref attribute.

I have a bean definition for an action class like below.

```
<bean name="/abc" class="com.example.actions.Action" scope="singleton">
    <property name="businessLogic" ref="/pqr"/>
</bean>
```

I am trying to inject another bean into this bean using ref attribute (ie "/pqr").

```
<bean name="/pqr" class="com.example.businesslogic.PqrBL" scope="prototype" />
```

Now my question how normal is it to use *name="/pqr"* kind of a notation for a bean which is not a definition for some action class ? By convention is it an acceptable normal scenario ?

PS: please let me know if information provided is incomplete or the question is not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring reference states that

```
The convention is to use the standard Java convention for instance field names when 
naming beans. That is, bean names start with a lowercase letter, and are camel-cased from
then on. Examples of such names would be (without quotes) 'accountManager', 
'accountService', 'userDao', 'loginController', and so forth.
```

It is not normal to use "/pqr" as a bean name but you can do it . I would prefer using more user friendly names to the beans than using a "path" .

Check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-beanname) for the convention .